# Review pane in the meta page

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

It seems odd that after an item is reviewed in the pane, it does not go away, and it stays in the pane (after refresh).

Comment: Seems like a [known bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111393/posts-ive-already-reviewed-show-up-in-the-review-section-again)

Comment: Does not occur ever on the main site. Then, whenever I get a new 30 items to review, the number to review goes down by 30.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Sathya [linked to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111393/posts-ive-already-reviewed-show-up-in-the-review-section-again) this bug was also reported on Meta Stack Overflow.

It has since been fixed, just cleaning up this bug report. (: